# SQL Query for two tables which only reviews non null values from one table to export matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created an application that fills one SQL table with over 2 million records.

I have also created another WinForms application that allows users to enter search criteria which then creates another SQL table on demand.
Table A is the table that has over 2 million records
Table B is the user created table.
Both tables have the same amount of fields.

In short I am looking to return only values that match from both tables. However the issue is that I want to ignore null values from the user created table. i.e.
User enters criteria in fields 1 and 2. I want to match on any record that meets those criteria even though the other fields are blank.

What I'm running into right now is that it won't match on the specific records because the user created table has a lot of null value where as the Table A does not.

I've tried a few different things.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TableB
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM TableA
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

Comment: A [mre] with sample data and desired results would go a long way to clarifying this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.* from T1 cross join T2
where   (T1.column1 = T2.column1 or T2.column1 is null)
    and (T1.column2 = T2.column2 or T2.column2 is null) ...
```